# does leaving pointers in functions cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

Suppose I have a function or class that maintains some pointers to other data objects, like so:

```
class MyObject {
    ...
    AnotherObject* o1, *o2;
    SomeObject* s1, *s2;
    ...
}

int main() {
    ...
    MyObject mo1 = new MyObject();
    ... // do stuff with mo1
    delete mo1;
}
```

Suppose they are assigned valid pointer values from elsewhere during/after initialization.

When I destroy the MyObject object after assigning those pointers inside, can a memory leak result if I do not null the pointers during destruction like so?:

```
MyObject::~MyObject() {
    o1 = nullptr;
    o2 = nullptr;
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: As long as every `new` is paired with a `delete`, nulling out the pointer objects or not doesn't make a difference. As long as you don't try to *use* them - then you'll get a different kind of error.

Comment: You should post the whole `MyObject` class, otherwise it's hard to say.

Comment: If you do `new` (or `new[]`) and don't have a corresponding `delete` (or `delete[]`) *then* you have a memory leak. Just having non-null pointers doesn't cause leaks. There is however an easier way of not having memory leaks: Don't use pointers or dynamic allocation yourself. Use [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) or [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) whenever you can, and you won't get any leaks.

Comment: Plenty of ways to shoot your leg off when you don't implement the rule of three and don't use std::shared_ptr<>.  So don't do that, it will hurt less.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't cause a memory leak. Note however that this:

```
MyObject mo1 = new MyObject();
// do stuff with mo1
delete mo1;
```

will result in a memory leak if `do stuff with mo1` throws an exception (which could be the case if it comprises references to `nullptr`). Therefore it's advisable not to use naked pointers like you do but smart pointers instead - this way RAII guarantees that your pointer will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks!

I wasn't worried about what `do stuff with mo1` would do when I wrote the question, but it's definitely worth considering anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you come from a Java background, where setting pointers to null is necessary to allow the garbage collector to reclaim other objects. If so, the answer is simple: no, that's not how it works in C++. Setting a pointer to null has no bearing whatsoever on memory usage, and there is no garbage collector anyway that could reclaim any memory.

Instead you are supposed to consider ownership. Most objects have one specific owner; once that owner is deleted, so are its owned objects. This is most conveniently modelled using unique_ptr instead of raw pointers. For objects that have more complex ownership, there is shared_ptr and weak_ptr.

Once again, there is no garbage collector, so any time you use `new` to create an object, somehow, somewhere there must be a corresponding `delete`. The easiest way to ensure such deletes are not forgotten is to use unique_ptr.

Also be wary of using `new` too often. Your `mo1` object can be allocated on the stack without any problem: it's lifetime is limited to one function (main), so why not use simply allocate it as `MyObject mo1;` - that's enough, no need to new or delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

No it would not. Memory leak happens because of a non-deleted memory which was allocated using `new`. Nulling a pointer is just a way to check it later if it was deleted or not and it has nothing to do with memory leak.

On the other hand, dealing with memory manually is not a the best way to achieve what you want. Smart pointers are exist (`std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`...). You should have a look on them.